# Acces violation when printing matrix in C/C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-management, matrix

So I wrote this code in order to read a matrix from a file using malloc function. It seems to save the matrix in the memory but when I try to print it, this pop-up with Access violation reading a location appears. I'm new to programming and IDK how to fix this (I left a comment where the program exits)...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int **mat(int **&m, int &i, int*&v) {
    FILE *f = fopen("in.txt", "r");
    i = 0;
    int j;

    char buffer[100];

    while (!feof(f)) {
        m = (int**) malloc(100 * sizeof (int**));

        j = 0;

        m[i] = NULL;

        fgets(buffer, 100, f);

        char*tok;
        tok = strtok(buffer, " \n");

        while (tok) {
            m[i] = (int*) malloc(50 * sizeof (int*));
            m[i][j] = (int) malloc(sizeof (int));

            m[i][j] = atoi(tok);
            j++;
            tok = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        }
        v[i] = (int) malloc(sizeof (int));
        v[i] = j;
        i++;
    }
    return m;
}

void print(int**&m, int &i, int*&v) {
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < v[k]; l++) {
            printf("%d ", m[k][l]); // The issue appears here
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void main() {
    int**m, i, *v;
    v = (int*) malloc(20 * sizeof (int));
    //v = NULL;
    m = mat(m, i, v);

    print(m, i, v);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What is `int **&m` ??

Comment: that's the integers matrix and I put the ampersand there in order to use the matrix in other funcions

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Looks like c++ damage. Probably unsalvageable.

Comment: Is `int &i` allowed as argument in c ?

Comment: @AlexPop This syntax is illegal and meaningless in C. If you are thinking C++, it would be a different story.

Comment: I may have used some c++ features

Comment: @AlexPop Without knowing that it will work in C or not ?

Comment: @AlexPop, the `&` syntax Eugene asked about resembles use of a C++ "feature" that goes by the name of "references".  C does not have such a feature, hence your code is not valid C.  Possibly you could fix that particular problem by changing `int **&m` to `int ***m` in the function declaration, and by changing `m` to `*m` everywhere in that function's body.

Comment: Using features you don't understand, and not knowing why you've used them?

Comment: @AlexPop, C++ and C are different languages.  If you "use C++ features" then you are writing C++, not C.

Comment: sorry for the missunderstanding, it is c++

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a real answer, but doesn't fit as a comment.

Sorry, but almost *all* your uses of `malloc` are incorrect, both the way you use them and *that* you use it in the first place.

I would try starting with

```
int main()
{
    int   mat[100][50];
    int   i;
    int   v[20];
```

and then try to write the code without the `malloc`s. You have all the `int`s you need right here, and don't have to allocate them separately.

Another thing is that `feof(f)` doesn't tell if the next read will succeed, but tells us if the previous read failed. Not very useful in a `while`-condition, as it triggers one round too late. Much better to check what `fgets` returns.

Comment: I acctually found my mistake. I answered my question... sorry for wasting your time...

Answer (score 0):

I found myself an answer, I put it here

```
int **mat(int **&m, int &i, int*&v) {
FILE *f = fopen("in.txt", "r");
i = 0;
int j;

char buffer[100];

while (!feof(f)) {
    m = (int**) realloc(m, (i+1) * sizeof (int*)); // Changed aloocation type and saw that i wrote sizeod(int**) instead of int*

    j = 0;

    m[i] = NULL;

    fgets(buffer, 100, f);

    char*tok;
    tok = strtok(buffer, " \n");

    while (tok) {
        m[i] = (int*) realoc(m[i], (j+1) * sizeof (int)); // Changed aloocation type and saw that i wrote sizeod(int**) instead of int*
        m[i][j] = (int) malloc(sizeof (int));

        m[i][j] = atoi(tok);
        j++;
        tok = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }
    v[i] = (int) malloc(sizeof (int));
    v[i] = j;
    i++;
}
return m;
}
```